# Content Organizer Rules Are Being Created Automatically?

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity, content-organizer, drop-off-library, content-organizer-rule

We have a drop off library that's been operational since 2017, and only recently (last month) we started seeing some odd behavior where after a file is uploaded, the file is moved correctly according to the existing rule that applies, but then a new content organizer rule is created using the file name as a target folder name.

So for example, if I upload a file named "test.png" with dropdown field setting a metdata field to "training aids", the content organizer rule would move the file to a document library called "Educational Materials" under a folder named "Visual Aids".

That still works, but now, a new content organizer rule will be created automatically whose actions are to move any files with the metadata field named "training aids" to a new folder named "Coffee Compass" under the library "Education Materials".

My earlier rule did not specify to create new folders based on metadata, and I don't see how that would result in a new content organizer rule being created anyway.

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior where content organizer rules are created automatically after a file is processed in the dropoff library? This is not desired and we didn't do anything deliberate to start such behavior. I'm not sure how I would do this even if I wanted to.

Comment: BTW, this is SharePoint Online.